# How to find credentials of Sandbox HDP-3.0.1 Atlas installed in Docker

Tags: ambari, hdp, hortonworks-sandbox, apache-atlas

`https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/3.html`

I am following above reference and get HDP installed in linux docker. Most of the services are running. Able to log into Ambari, Ranger as admin and raj_ops respectively but could not log into Atlas. The strange thing is that following below to add policy in Ranger results in 401 error.
https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/configuring-atlas/content/configuring_atlas_authorization.html

The authorization policy is set to Ranger.

The archive scripts used to install above HDP image.
https://archive.cloudera.com/hwx-sandbox/hdp/hdp-3.0.1/HDP_3.0.1_docker-deploy-scripts_18120587fc7fb.zip

Is there any docs that could help me finding creds to access Atlas?
or
Fix Ranger issue?

Let me know if anymore information could help in understanding the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i found answer of this question somewhere but forgot the link. 
Creds for Atlas in Sandbox HDP-3.0.1 is below:

```
admin/admin123
```

Below are for Data Steward

```
holger_gov/holger_gov
```

Answer (score 2):

By default Atlas in HDP Sandbox is disable.

Go to http://localhost:1080 and then click on Advanced HDP Quick Links.

There you can find creds of Atlas which is (username & password: holger_gov) and also a link for Enable Atlas Service (https://www.cloudera.com/tutorials/tag-based-policies-with-apache-ranger-and-apache-atlas/.html#step-1-enable-ranger-audit-to-solr)

Comment: I am top voting this answer as it will be useful for many vistors. But the original question was intended to find creds for admin user. holger_gov is Data Steward. By the way, I answered my own question as it was found quite earlier but i forgot my question in here. Thank you!